# Looking for a compatible M.2 drive for my motherboard

Tags: motherboard, ssd, data-storage

I'm looking to get rid of my old HDD (my xbox HDD is dying so prob put it in that) and replace it with an SSD. I would like to make use of the M.2 port on my motherboard if I can.

This is my motherboard [Gigabyte GA-B150M-D3H](https://www.gigabyte.com/uk/Motherboard/GA-B150M-D3H-rev-10#ov)

I had looked at getting this [WD Blue](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B073SB2MXT/?ref=idea_lv_dp_ov_d) but just before hitting buy I noticed that the transfer rate wasn't what I was expecting.

I don't know much about M.2 so I'm not sure what kind will work with my motherboard.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The motherboard specifications say the following about your M.2 port:

> 1 x M.2 Socket 3 connector (Socket 3, M key, type 2242/2260/2280 SATA & PCIe x4/x2/x1 SSD support)

That means *any* M.2 drive should be supported by your motherboard. Except drives that are wider than 22mm, or longer than 80mm. (2280 = 22 x 80 mm)

Comment: Ah great thanks!. Would this one work then? [Sabrent](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07LGF54XR/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=A3OPWMF9XBYSSI&psc=1) I also wonder what the difference in NVME and NAND is and whether that should be a deciding factor for my motherboard?

Comment: As long as your motherboard doesn't give you any unexpected headaches that SSD will be compatible. I'm not sure how frequent those 'headaches' actually happen with newer boards, when M.2 was new it was a possibility that specific SSD and motherboard/BIOS combinations had issues.